# Stop Blinking of display block/none with timer in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, events, settimeout

I can't seem to figure out the logic here. I have a an element that hides until the mouse is moved (`utilBar`) and i want it to stay displayed even after the timer ends *IF* the mouse is still moving. Obviously what I figured was, on mouse moving start a timer and display the element and if there is another mouse move after the first one stop the timer and start it again repeatedly therefore the timer never ends as long as the mouse is moving.

the problem is my element is blinking after the 1000 milliseconds is up flashing on/off as I move the mouse. I think I'm just tripping on the logic here, but I can't figure it out.

```
//Separate function to pass in utilBarTimer into the setTimeout
function timerFunction(utilBarTimer){
  self.iframe.addEventListener('mousemove',function(){
    clearTimeout(window.utilBarTimer);
  });
  utilBar.style.display = 'none';
}
self.iframe.addEventListener('mousemove',function(){
  utilBar.style.display = 'block';
  var utilBarTimer = window.setTimeout(function(){
    timerFunction(utilBarTimer)
  },1000);
});
```

Comment: It looks like you're passing the timer itself to timerFunction, so why are you calling clearTimeout on the window.utilBarTimer?

Comment: Not sure i understand? Im canceling out the timerFunction and starting a new one each time. window.utilBarTimer === utilBarTimer. If i remove "window." (if thats what you mean?) then the same thing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They way you are currently doing it is creating a new `EventListener` that will clear the timeout every time the mouse moves.  I think the logic you're looking for is this:

```
var utilBar = document.getElementById('utilBar'),
    utilBarTimer;

window.addEventListener('mousemove', function() {
    utilBar.style.display = 'block';

    // if we have a timer already running, kill it out
    if (utilBarTimer) {
        clearTimeout(utilBarTimer);   
    }

    // begin a new timer that hides our object after 1000 ms
    utilBarTimer = window.setTimeout(function() {
        utilBar.style.display = 'none';
    }, 1000);
});
```

Here's the **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmFMx/)** of it in action.

Comment: Awh, yes. I didn't even think about checking if there was a utilBarTimer set. Thanks, working like a charm!